# rvalue for indirection operator in c

Tags: c

I am confused about working of the below statement:

```
*ptr++->str
```

First `++` operator is applied to `ptr` which returns rvalue. Next operator is `->` has to be applied. Doesn't `->` operator require lvalue?

Comment: Why do you think that is the case?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, by the way.

Comment: It compiles in gcc.I got the output.

Comment: I don't know the definition of "ptr". But I doubt if there is any definition possible to allow the above expression to be valid.

Comment: @vindhya what does your data-structure look like? I am also using GCC and It doesn't work.

Comment: The language specification says "The first operand of the `->` operator shall have type 'pointer to qualified or unqualified structure' or 'pointer to qualified or unqualified union'." No requirement that it be an lvalue. If you have a question about what is legal in a language, the standard is a good place to check.

Comment: @wildplasser:ptr is pointer to struct which contains pointer to the integer

Comment: A valid program containing the expression: http://ideone.com/Obeg9

Comment: @vindhya in what situation would you have an integer named 'str'?

Comment: I just found a way to define the struct, but it still does not make sense.

Comment: Basically the same as @aschepler 's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesnt `->` operator require lvalue?

No.  See section 6.5.2.3 of the C99 standard:

> The first operand of the `->` operator shall have type ‘‘pointer to qualified or unqualified
>   structure’’ or ‘‘pointer to qualified or unqualified union’’, and the second operand shall
>   name a member of the type pointed to.
>
> ...
>
> A postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier designates a member
>   of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member of the object to
>   which the first expression points, and is an lvalue.

And that's all it says on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible definition for the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct fuzz {
        char *str;
        } stuff = {"Hi there!"} ;

struct fuzz *ptr = &stuff;

int main()
{
char ch='@';

printf("Before: p=%p, ch=%c\n", (void*) ptr, ch);

ch = *ptr++->str;

printf("After: p=%p, ch=%c\n", (void*) ptr, ch);


return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before: p=0x601020, ch=@
After: p=0x601028, ch=H
```

And the output proves that the pointer expression is an lvalue. Modifyable, if str would not point to a string constant.

Comment: How does this prove that the pointer expression is an lvalue?

Comment: Because it evaluates to a (dereferenced) pointer expression. Pointer to character in my case.

Comment: But `*` doesn't require its operand to be an lvalue.